How to guide Junior Lecturers in teaching a short Mathematics course
I joined a university recently as a senior lecturer. I became senior recently too and with the new environment (new university is private and previously I have been in a state university), continuously I experience doubts on how I should respond to some situations. Even previously I had doubtful situations though...
I am kind of introverted and I highly appreciate your advices and any insights regarding practical situations on how a senior lecturer should behave, how she can create an environment to guide the assistant/junior lecturers and also to maintain good social connection.
My specific problem is however below:
I have been asked to guide some junior lecturers to conduct a kind a a fun type mathematics short course for a group of undergraduates who are hoping to come to the university for the first time after a couple of months. Their degree is Bachelor of Computer science but they will be studying some mathematics modules too. What is the best way to guide the junior lecturers to do this, as a senior lecturer?
Currently, I planned to tell them to mainly teach them basic algebra computations and refresh their memory on that, do more exercises on that - may be in a more engaging way like by asking the students themselves to come and do it on the board, do a few math games in the class, do quizes etc. But what else can I possibly do?
Also please note that in the setting that I'm placed in, it is importsnt that through the way I guide the I show that I'm well professional, and I have some nice techniques. But how can I do it?
P.S. The junior lecturers are kind of stubborn too. What type of a tact I should use to overcome it?
Thank you very much in advance.

How experienced are you as a teacher? As a pedagogy designer?

I changed the topline question to better match your specific question.

Maybe a better fit at math educators SE?

I suggest that, rather than "telling them what to do" you hold a "round table discussion" with a few sessions in which people, including yourself, can offer suggestions and can comment on them.
If this series of sessions runs concurrently with the short course, all the better, since people can have a chance to comment on what seems to be effective.
Provide coffee and snacks if possible. This will increase the social interaction component, hopefully fulfilling some of your wider goals. You could also invite other experienced teachers to one or more of the sessions to get a broader perspective.
